# В чём смысл «общих вопросов»?

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, метки

На сайте есть метка [общие-вопросы](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%89%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%8b). На мой взгляд, эта метка совершенно не добавляет смысла вопросам, следовательно она не нужна. Что такое эти «общие вопросы»? Они в любом случае относятся к русскому языку, значит их можно как-то классифицировать.

Предлагаю перебрать все вопросы по этой метке, удалить метку и, при необходимости, поставить другие, более осмысленные метки.

Answer (score 1):

Для метки добавлено описание:

> Для вопросов, которые трудно отнести к какой-либо определенной метке, однако их связь с русским языком очевидна.